# Differentiating Colored Masks in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

The project aims at detecting colored squares and accordingly send control signals to the Micro-Controller

Here is my output of the processed Image..

RED :

[image]

GREEN :

[image]

If RED Square is detected the matlab sends character 'R' through serial port
If GREEN Square is detected the matlab sends character 'G' through serial port

Any idea/technique to differentiate the processed images and send data ??

Like if RED Square appears boolean `red=true` and when GREEN suware appears boolean `green=true`

Later or I could check the boolean and send the character if it is `true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image processing part is really easy, if all of your images are as simple as you are showing in your example.  You can simply check which channel is more dominant, red or green.

```
   green = im(:,:,2);
   red = im(:,:,1);
   if sum( green(:)) > sum(red(:))
       % Send green!
   else
       % Send red!
   end
```

If the images are not that simple, you can convert the image to `HSV` color space, and check out what is the dominant `Hue`, except for those that have `Sat` less than some threshold. The latter part is needed in order to remove the black pixels from the decision (They tend to have almost random `Hue`).

You can read here about [controlling serial ports](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.html)